# D3jsのグラフを1ページに複数枚表示できない

Tags: javascript, php, html, d3.js

初めて投稿します。html/JavaScript劇的初心者です。
今、ウェブサイトでd3jsを使って複数枚グラフを表示しようとしているのですが、なぜか後のグラフしか表示されません。
なにかd3jsを使う上で気をつけないといけない点ありますでしょうか。

ソースコードを添付します。

HTML

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>W2V execution</title>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v0.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <h1> KeyWord1： <?php echo $input_kw[0] ?> </h1>
          <div id="bubble"></div>
          <script src = "bubblechart.js"></script>
        </td>
        <td>
          <h1> KeyWord2： <?php echo $input_kw[1] ?> </h1>
          <div id="bubble2"></div> 
          <script src = "bubblechart2.js"></script>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

bubblechart.js

```js
var diameter = 350,
format = d3.format(",d"),
color = d3.scale.category20c();

var bubble = d3.layout.pack()
  .sort(null)
  .size([diameter, diameter])
  .padding(1.5);

var svg = d3.select("#bubble").append("svg")
  .attr("width", diameter)
  .attr("height", diameter)
  .attr("class", "bubble");

d3.json("/data/kw1.txt", function(error, root) {
  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(bubble.nodes(classes(root))
    .filter(function(d) { return !d.children; }))
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

  node.append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return d.className + ": " + format(d.value); });

  node.append("circle")
      .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r; })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.packageName); });

  node.append("text")
      .attr("dy", ".3em")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(d) { return d.className.substring(0, d.r / 3); });
});

function classes(root) {
  var classes = [];

  function recurse(name, node) {
    if (node.children) node.children.forEach(function(child) { recurse(node.name, child); });
    // else classes.push({packageName: name, className: node.name, value: node.size});
    else classes.push({packageName: name, className: node.Keyword, value: node.Value});
  }

  recurse(null, root);
  return {children: classes};
}
```

bublechart2.js

```js
var diameter = 350,
format = d3.format(",d"),
color = d3.scale.category20c();

var bubble = d3.layout.pack()
  .sort(null)
  .size([diameter, diameter])
  .padding(1.5);

var svg = d3.select("#bubble2").append("svg")
  .attr("width", diameter)
  .attr("height", diameter)
  .attr("class", "bubble");

d3.json("/data/kw2.txt", function(error, root) {
  var node2 = svg.selectAll(".node2")
    .data(bubble.nodes(classes(root))
    .filter(function(d) { return !d.children; }))
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node2")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

  node2.append("title")
       .text(function(d) { return d.className + ": " + format(d.value); });

  node2.append("circle")
       .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r; })
       .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.packageName); });

  node2.append("text")
       .attr("dy", ".3em")
       .style("text-anchor", "middle")
       .text(function(d) { return d.className.substring(0, d.r / 3); });
});

function classes(root) {
  var classes = [];

  function recurse(name, node2) {
    if (node2.children) node2.children.forEach(function(child) { recurse(node2.name, child); });
    // else classes.push({packageName: name, className: node2.name, value: node2.size});
    else classes.push({packageName: name, className: node2.Keyword, value: node2.Value});
  }

  recurse(null, root);
  return {children: classes};
}
```

Comment: できるだけシンプルに削ったソースコードを載せるといいと思います． cf : [良い質問をするには? - ヘルプ センター - スタック・オーバーフロー](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: 前にstackoverflow.comでHighchartsの場合で[似たような質問へ回答](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35059984/stop-highcharts-overwriting-containers/35061448#35061448)したことがありますが、その時はfor文の書き方を変えれば意図したとおりに表示できるケースでした。いずれにしてもソースコードは載せたほうが良いと思います。(無いと、どこをどのように直せばなぜ動くようになるのかを回答者が説明できない為)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 原因

jsファイルを2つに分けていますが、これらに定義されている変数や関数は、同じHTMLに読み込まれると同じスコープ(有効範囲)になります。
(1つのjsファイルにまとめて書いたのと同じ状態になります)

そのため同じ名前の変数や関数があると、より後に宣言されている定義(内容)で上書きされます。

今回該当するのは下記のもので、これらがHTML上で後に読み込まれている`bublechart2.js`の定義で上書きされて、後のグラフしか表示されなくなっています。

変数：

- `diameter`
- `format`
- `color`
- `bubble`
- `svg`

関数：

- `function classes(root)`

**`svg`以外の変数**は、どちらも全く同じ値が代入されているため、(今のところ)上書きされてても動作に影響はないかと思います。

`function classes(root)`は、関数の処理の内容が全く同じなので、(今のところ)上書きされてても動作に影響はないかと思います。

#### 修正方法

bublechart2.jsの`svg`を`svg2`等の別の名前にすることで解決できるかと思います。
`d3.json("/data/kw2.txt", function(error, root) {...})`内の`svg`も一緒に変える必要があります。

修正後のbublechart2.js

```js
(前略)

// `svg2`へ変更
var svg2 = d3.select("#bubble2").append("svg")
  .attr("width", diameter)
  .attr("height", diameter)
  .attr("class", "bubble");

d3.json("/data/kw2.txt", function(error, root) {
  // `svg2`へ変更
  var node2 = svg2.selectAll(".node2")
    .data(bubble.nodes(classes(root))
    .filter(function(d) { return !d.children; }))
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node2")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

  node2.append("title")
       .text(function(d) { return d.className + ": " + format(d.value); });

  node2.append("circle")
       .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r; })
       .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.packageName); });

  node2.append("text")
       .attr("dy", ".3em")
       .style("text-anchor", "middle")
       .text(function(d) { return d.className.substring(0, d.r / 3); });
});

(後略)
```

#### 余談

JavaScriptのfunctionは新しいスコープを作ります。functionの外部で定義されている変数と同じ名前の変数をfunction内で宣言した場合、function内で定義した変数が参照されます。

```js
var a = 0;
var svg = "svg";

function first() {
  // トップレベルの`a`とは別の変数として扱われる
  var a = 1;
  console.log("first: " + a);

  // 外に定義されている`svg`が参照される
  console.log("first: " + svg);
}

function second() {
  // トップレベルの`a`やfirstの`a`とは別の変数として扱われる
  var a = 2;
  console.log("second: " + a);
}

// ブラウザの開発者ツールのConsoleに1とsvgが出力される
first();

// 2が出力される
second();

// 0が出力される
console.log("toplevel: " + a);
```

つまり、今回のソースコードで`d3.json("...", function(error, root) {...})`のfunction内でそれぞれ`var node`、`var node2`と別々の名前が付けられていますが、それぞれ別のfunctionなので同じ名前を付けていても別の変数として扱われ、意図した通りに動作します。

Comment: harrry0000さん、丁寧な回答、さらには質問文の編集までしていただき本当にありがとうございます。コードを直したところ無事動くようになりました。